# How to restrict DVD access using Windows Server 2003 Group Policy?

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy

I have a Windows Server 2003 DC with 3 Win7 (32) desktops.  I want to use an GPO to restrict the DVD on all the desktops (Either 'hide' or not have available) for all domain users except for domain users with local admin rights. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use MMC GPO snapin and set the rules you wish for non admin users. For local user you will only have two group choice, admin and non admin.

You cannot use gpedit.msc directly because it will allow you to edit computer's rules and current user's rules only.

You can look at the documentation here if you don't find the CD specific rules.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555324 (HOWTO: Use Group Policy to disable USB, CD-ROM, Floppy Disk)

Then restrict whatever you want, it can be more than hiding/disable cdrom drives.

Or if you are not willing to create the GPO rule, you can use a tool like DeviceLock
http://devicelock.com/